# Ruby output numbers to 2 decimal places

Tags: json, ruby, number-formatting

I'm having trouble serializing my ruby object to json, more specifically the format of the numbers.
I have written an rspec test to illustrate my issue more precisely.

```
expected = '{ "foo": 1.00, "bar": 4.50, "abc": 0.00, "xyz": 1.23 }'

it 'serializes as expected' do
  my_hash = { "foo": 1, "bar": 4.5, "abc": 0, "xyz": 1.23}
  expect(my_to_json_method(my_hash)).to eq expected
end
```

This is the case that I am having trouble with. I can use the sprintf but how do I get the string output as shown in the above example?

Comment: please try this,
`test = { "foo": (sprintf "%.2f","1.0"), "bar": (sprintf "%.2f","4.50"), "abc": (sprintf "%.2f","0") }`

Comment: The output of those values are strings. So the formatting works but I would like the result not string quoted in the result.

Comment: @mcbain83 are you trying to store monetary values?

Comment: Yes thats correct.. I'm not sure that this behaviour is that important in the json string.. but still i'm wanting to see if this is possible at all now.

Comment: **WARNING**: Floating point numbers, as the name implies, have no fixed precision. If you want precise values, which is *especially* important for money, use [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead. **DO NOT** use floating point numbers for monetary calculations. A floating point number is a precise *approximation* of a value, not a precise representation of one. If you're using JSON for transport, I'd strongly recommend using a unit small enough that you never need fractions, for example, cents vs. dollars.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm aware of the pitfalls of using floating point numbers and money. In fact I'm using the money gem instead which does all that for me. The problem still stands though. ( I avoided mentioning this was for money.. I wanted to keep this question focused on formatting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should not use floats to represent monetary values. So instead, let's use a more appropriate type: (there's also the Ruby [Money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem)

```
require 'bigdecimal'

my_hash = {
  foo: BigDecimal.new('1.00'),
  bar: BigDecimal.new('4.50'),
  abc: BigDecimal.new('0.00'),
  xyz: BigDecimal.new('1.23')
}
```

There are several options to represent monetary values. All of the following JSON strings are valid according to the JSON specification and all require special treatment upon parsing. It's up to you to choose the most appropriate.

> **Note:** I'm implementing a custom `to_json` method to convert the `BigDecimal` instances to JSON using Ruby's default JSON library. This is just for demonstration purposes, you should generally not patch core (or stdlib) classes.

---

#### 1. Numbers with fixed precision

This is what you asked for. Note that many JSON libraries will parse these numbers as floating point values by default.

```
class BigDecimal
  def to_json(*)
    '%.2f' % self
  end
end
puts my_hash.to_json
```

Output:

```json
{"foo":1.00,"bar":4.50,"abc":0.00,"xyz":1.23}
```

---

#### 2. Numbers as strings

This will work across all JSON libraries, but storing numbers as strings doesn't look quite right to me.

```
class BigDecimal
  def to_json(*)
    '"%.2f"' % self
  end
end
puts my_hash.to_json
```

Output:

```json
{"foo":"1.00","bar":"4.50","abc":"0.00","xyz":"1.23"}
```

---

#### 3. Numbers as integers

Instead of representing monetary values as fractional numbers, you simply output the *cents* as whole numbers. This is what I usually do.

```
class BigDecimal
  def to_json(*)
    (self * 100).to_i.to_s
  end
end
puts my_hash.to_json
```

Output:

```json
{"foo":100,"bar":450,"abc":0,"xyz":123}
```

Comment: Thank you! yes I'm using the money gem. I wanted to avoid the 'what type to use for money issue' discussion because I wanted to focus on the formatting issue. Which I think you have answered..

Comment: This is a great answer, though I’d better suggest prepending custom modules and/or using refinements instead of monkeypatching core libs.

Comment: @mcbain83 in that case, I'd use `{"foo":{"cents":100,"currency":"USD"}}`

Comment: @mudasobwa hence the yellow note ;)

Comment: @Stefan let's assume I can't change the expected output. Is there anything else you would suggest using the money gem? All the formatting options seem to output strings.

Comment: @mcbain83 Also please be aware of `JPY` having *zero* decimals and `KWD`, `OMR` and some others have *three* decimals. This value may be queried against `Money::Currency#exponent`: `'10_000'.to_money('OMR').currency.exponent #⇒ 3`.

Comment: @mcbain83 I don't understand your comment. JSON is a string format, so you have to output a string. Take a look at my `to_json` implementations – they all return strings.

Comment: @Stefan yes sorry I know it sounds confusing. I mean the "foo"  value is a number eg '{ "foo":1.00 }'   and not '{ "foo":"1.00"}'

Comment: @mcbain83 not really, `{"foo":1.00}` is a (JSON) string and `1.00` is a substring within that string (it becomes a number when you parse the string). See https://gist.github.com/sos4nt/d46c4753b2d99ea2fef536abda25631e

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean now.. I see your point.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

User Sprintf

sprintf('%.2f', 5.5)

And simply interpolate into your JSON as an ERB template.

Comment: humm erb may work.. what would the template look like? Feels like it could be a little messy with a whole bunch of conditionals..i'll try make one and see if I can post a result...

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `sprintf` and can take as many decimal points as you needed by mentioning `%.(number)f`.

Eg: For two decimals, `%.2f`

Here is a real implementation,

```
2.2.2 :019 > test = { "foo": (sprintf "%.2f","1.11"), "bar": (sprintf "%.2f","4.55"), "abc": (sprintf "%.2f","0.2") }

 => {:foo=>"1.11", :bar=>"4.55", :abc=>"0.20"}
```

[Here is the reference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

Comment: How would you output the same values *not* as strings but as number values?

Comment: `test = { "foo": (sprintf "%.2f","1.11").to_f, "bar": (sprintf "%.2f","4.55").to_f, "abc": (sprintf "%.2f","0.2").to_f }`

Comment: When you use the .to_f on "1.30" result formatted string you get 1.3 which is back to the original issue.

Comment: Have a look at my reworked question.. I've written it as a rspec test to be more accurate with what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am not sure, we can achieve two decimals after one `0` in floating points, I researched many places. why cant you change your test case?

Comment: Do you think this is impossible? :P I could change the test case but I want to see if this is possible. I think an erb template would work, I'm trying that out now.

Comment: I didn't say it is impossible, I just said I am not sure. I will also check for a solution in between :)

Comment: @Sravan Converting to string and back is pointless since the [`round`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Float.html#method-i-round) function exists. This recommendation to `sprintf`-*all the things* is also baffling.

Comment: @tadman, yes correct, I just converted to string and left as it is now.

Comment: With every edit this code gets more and more outrageous. That's really the opposite of what Ruby is all about: Don't Repeat Yourself is a driving principle, and this code is absurdly repetitive.

Comment: @taddman, I just edited my answer back to first, which helps in formatting the number, to two decimal places and its fine upto that. why downvote then?

Comment: @Sravan I want to avoid this being returned in the json object as as string.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts '{' << my_hash.map { |k, v| %Q|"#{k}": #{"%.2f" % v}| }.join(', ') << '}'
#⇒ {"foo": 1.00, "bar": 4.50, "abc": 0.00, "xyz": 1.23}
```